# Text file to Tuple to Dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains the following information:

```
Britney 2 3 4 5 1 23 6
Jessica 5 1 5 3 2 33 1 5 2 5 61 2
Mathew 2 33 1 4 2 5 5 2 3 
Sofia 8 3 1 2 3 52 1 5 2 3 51 25 23 1 2 6
```

I am supposed to write a function that takes the name and assigns it as a key in a `dictionary`

As for the value of the key, that's a bit more complicated.

The function needs to read through the numbers, the FIRST number (starting from left to right) indicates HOW MANY numbers will be in the TUPLE. And then it goes through the number and picks the second number - nth number.

For example.

```
Britney 2 3 4 5 1 23 6
```

The first number `2` indicates that the NEXT two number will be the tuple value for the key `Britney`. So Britney has the value `(3, 4)`

Likewise:

```
Sofia 8 3 1 2 3 52 1 5 2 3 51 25 23 1 2 6
```

`Sofia` has the value `(3, 1, 2, 3, 52, 1, 5, 2)`

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
input_file = open("namesandnumbers.txt", "r")
the_dict = {}
for line in input_file:
    initial = line.replace("\n","").split(" ")
    key = initial[0]
```

but I can't figure out what to do next, and I am unsure about using `split(" ")` as there is space between the name and numbers, but between numbers themselves as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. You were on the right track, the part you were missing is slicing the string up. I'd suggest you read more about that here: [cutting and slicing strings in python](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/)

```
input_file = open("namesandnumbers.txt", "r")
the_dict = {}
for line in input_file:
    initial = line.replace("\n","").split(" ")
    key = initial[0]
    number = int(initial[1])
    value = tuple([int(x) for x in initial[2: number + 2]])
    the_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: I tried something similar, and then I tried what you said (code-to-code), but this gives me an output as: `'2', '3', '5', '6'`. I can't seem to remove the `'` from the digits. Would it help if I converted it to a list? But how will I pass the key to the next function if I do that.

Comment: @Nume those are strings and you need to convert them to ints. check [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: Thanks @SirParselot - updated to convert to numbers using a list comprehension

Comment: could you please help explain `[int(x) for x in initial[2: number + 2]]` - we haven't learned how to do a one-line for code

Comment: See list comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: it's called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) - you can think of it as performing int(x) for each item in the list initial[2: number + 2]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply `.strip()` the line instead of replacing the `\n`. Then simply use slicing:

```
the_dict = {}

for line in input_file:
    data = line.strip().split()  # no need to specify " ", it will use whitespace already
    key = data[0]
    length = int(data[1])
    data = tuple(data[2:length+2])
    the_dict[key] = data
```

**Bonus one-liner**

```
the_dict = {data[0]:data[2:int(data[1])+2] for data in (line.strip().split() for line in open('somefile'))}
```

Comment: data should be `tuple(data[2:length+2])` since you should be grabbing n starting at the second index. Also, you might want to map the numbers to ints

Comment: `File "Testing.py", line 198, in get_names_num_tuple_dict
    length = int(line[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'` I am getting the following error when I try that

Comment: @Nume my bad - that should've been `data[1]` - fixed in my answer

Comment: could you explain as to why data[1:length] was wrong? can't seem to figure that out

Comment: If you want the tuple elements to be `int` instead of `str`, you may have to convert each element to `int`.

Comment: @Nume `data[1:length]` will slice from index 1 to length so for sofia it will get `(8,3,1,2,3,52,1)` instead of `(3, 1, 2, 3, 52, 1, 5, 2)`

Comment: is it possible to do `int(data)` to get the values assigned to the key as int instead?

Comment: @Nume No, data is a tuple and you cannot convert a tuple into an int but you can do `tuple(map(int, data[2:length+2]))`

Comment: Or even better, use a generator expression instead of map: `tuple(int(d) for d in data[2:length+2])`

Comment: thank you. i appreciate the help and breakdown of the code.

Comment: @Nume [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are the `[thing for thing in iterable]` that you're looking for. Also see [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). The one-liner that I showed you makes use of a generator expression and a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Answer (score 0):

Well my two cents:

```
data = """Britney 2 3 4 5 1 23 6
Jessica 5 1 5 3 2 33 1 5 2 5 61 2
Mathew 2 33 1 4 2 5 5 2 3 
Sofia 8 3 1 2 3 52 1 5 2 3 51 25 23 1 2 6"""
lst = data.split("\n")
dct = {}
for elem in lst:
    nom, nb, *elem = elem.split(" ")
    dct[nom] = tuple([int(x) for x in elem[:int(nb)]])
print(dct)
```

Result:

```
{'Mathew': (33, 1), 'Jessica': (1, 5, 3, 2, 33), 'Sofia': (3, 1, 2, 3, 52, 1, 5, 2), 'Britney': (3, 4)}
```